# Sitecore SXA 500 custom error page not working

Tags: sxa, error-handling

I am using Sitecore 8.2 along with SXA. We have 404 and 500 custom error pages configured in Sitecore. 404 custom error page is working but I am unable to get 500 custom friendly error page whenever server error gets thrown. Instead a server error page with stack trace gets thrown.
Does anyone have any suggestion to make custom 500 error page being displayed when an internal server error occurs.

Comment: Do you have `<customErrors mode="On" />` in your web.config?

Comment: i just checked..it is 'off' in web.config as follows:  <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="500" />     I can make mode="On" but I am not sure what absolute/relative url to put in defaultRedirect as we do not have any .cshtml view in my project. We have 500 page as content page in sitecore

Comment: Can you try to replace your customerrors tag with `<customErrors mode="On" />` without any defaultRedirect?

Comment: Hi Marek, No success yet....i tried using customErrors tag without any default redirect in web.config <customErrors mode="On" />   but it shows server error page only instead of custom error page. Pls suggest

Answer (score 6):

Assign 404 and 505 pages in your settings, by selecting the relevant pages by going `/sitecore/content/{Environment}/{DemoSXASite}/Settings/` in the "Error Handling section"

[image]

For the 500 page you have to do a little trick, once you have designed the pages completely.

- go to `/sitecore/content/{Environment}/{DemoSXASite}/Settings/Site`
- Grouping/DemoSXASite Select the tab from top navigation "ERROR HANDLING"
- Click on Generate static page.

[image]

Here is my blog [link](https://isaadansari.wordpress.com/2018/07/04/setting-up-the-not-found-and-internal-server-error-pages-with-sxa-how-to-implement-series/) for reference, And don't forget to publish full site once done.

Comment: Can you also add that the page must already be linked on the settings item before you generate the static page?

Comment: Hi, I have followed this step and clicked on 'Generate static error page'. After that i will publish whole site. Do i need to do any more step like editing my web.config and changing customError tag to <customErrors mode="On" />. Currently customError tag is: 
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />

Comment: If that did not work try `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />` this is what I have configured and that works fine @Rachit

Comment: @MichaelWest In this question, I assumed that the pages are already setup, because the 404 page was working. so It would be unnecessary. I have share a reference link for that too.

Comment: Hi michael, my 404 and 500 pages are already linked correctly in Error Handling section in Settings.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I am recommending you add that detail to your answer because it would be a necessary step. Makes for a more complete answer, rather than relying on external links.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWest for the recommendation, already edited, will make sure for the next time. thnx

Comment: Hi @Sam , I have tried the above steps..no success. I also tried with <customErrors mode="On" /> and then with <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" /> .....It still shows  server error page. No custom error page getting dispalyed.

Comment: Check if your generated 500 page is there in your website root?

Comment: @Sam, no i do not see any 500 related page at physical location: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\[MySite]\Website    ........Pls let me know where shd i check exactly and what should be the generated 500 page name

Comment: The path is `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/[yourinstance]/ErrorPages/Yourwebsite.html` if it is there, check the content of it. The 500 is configured correctly.

Comment: @sam, i checked at mentioned path-C:/inetpub/wwwroot/[yourinstance]/  ....There is no folder created for ErrorPages and no html generated. I tried generating static error page again but no 500 page created. Am i missing something?

Comment: If it is not generated, then you might have missed some step. try following the steps carefully. then let me know

Comment: How would you handle the last step ('Click on Generate static page') for content delivery servers?

Comment: you have to generate it on every CD server

Comment: Hey Sam i am facing similar issue could you please let me know how did you fixed this error

Comment: Check this link for complete steps https://isaadansari.wordpress.com/2018/07/04/setting-up-the-not-found-and-internal-server-error-pages-with-sxa-how-to-implement-series/

Comment: yes it's working we need to put this setting  customErrors mode="On"

Comment: I did struggle with this as well, followed the setup but - it generated the error page in CM, so step 1 was to move it onto cd server. and then step2 was to update web.config. not only add mode="RemoteOnly" but also defaultRedirect="ErrorPages/<yourErrorPage>.html"

Answer (score 1):

@Rachit, I got same error when I tried to generate static error page. After looking at logs, the sitecore is actually trying to use the Content Management URL for 404 and 500 error pages which caused the error message "Error page did not load. Make sure you published your content."

To successfully generate error page, please make sure you login to CM via the tenant site host name for example: **sxasitename.sxa.com/sitecore**. If you use only sxa.com/sitecore to generate the error page, you will get errors.

After generated error pages, you can find static html error page under your root path such as 
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/[yourinstance]/ErrorPages/SXASiteName.html

Comment: A little unrelated - but is there any config in addition to it adding the file to that location?  We were trying to deploy it to other environments so I'm wondering if I just need to push the file, or if there's either file or database config that goes along with it.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same steps as mentioned above but the 500 Static Error Page was not getting generated. I found that apart from the above steps, we also have to make sure that the **CD Site is running over HTTPS**